# Is $i \times 0 =0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Is $i \times 0 =0$?
That is $\sqrt{-1} \times 0 = 0$?,
I am asking this question because I could not make sense of why it is equal to 0

Please answer this and confirm. I know that this is a simple conceptual question. But this part of a proof.

Comment: More generally, $(a+bi)(c+di)=ac-bd+(ad+bc)i$. Now use $0+0i=0$.

Comment: @J.G. But isn't that a bit circular ?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I presented the definition of multiplication on $\Bbb C$, together with an easily verified expression for the field's identity. I suppose the "circular" part, the "assuming your conclusion" part, is assuming the OP meant $0$ to be $0+0i$. What else would it be?

Comment: @J.G. Writing $0+0i=0$ looks a lot like assuming $0\times i=0$ to me. But if you treat $a+bi$ as a formal expression (or if you identify it with the pair $(a,b)$ or a certain kind of square matrix) then I agree that it is not circular. Maybe I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Which is just as well, because we want the $d=0$ case to coincide with the "obvious" multiplication by reals, viz. $(a+bi)c=ac+bci$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, take a commutative ring $R$ or a field such as the complex numbers, then zero is absorbing.

Indeed, let $a\in R$. We have $0 = 0 + 0$ and so by multiplying with $a$, $0a = (0+0)a = 0a + 0a$. Adding $-0a$ (additive inverse of $0a$ with $0a + (-0a)=0$) gives $0 = 0a$.